# Как вставить символы переноса строк (#13#10) в Memo при автопереносе строки?

Tags: delphi, текст, перенос-слов

Есть Memo со свойствами:

```
WordWrap := True;
ScrollBars := ssVertical;
```

Если вставить в него строку длиннее строки Memo, происходит автоперенос и часть вставляемой строки переносится. При этом символы переноса `#13#10` не вставляются, а хотелось бы. Как перехватить событие автопереноса, или свойство Memo которое включает автовставку символов `#13#10` при автопереносе?

Comment: Нужно всего лишь писать не `#10#13`, а `#13#10`. Тогда все получится.

Answer (score 2):

Компонент *ТMemo* не осуществляет никакого преобразование текста, автоперенос происходит только в момент отрисовки компонента средствами *WinAPI* (например при использовании функция `DrawText`). Сам автоперенос сложная штука, т.к. зависит от параметров отрисовки, главным из которых являются атрибуты шрифта. Т.е. для одного семейства шрифтов перенос будет в одном месте, для другого в другом.

Простых способов вставить `#10#13` с учетом привязки к `Canvas` в *Delphi* нет.

Как вариант, парсить строку по вашим правилам (пробелы, точки, тире) и использовать метод `Canvas.TextWidth` для получения требуемой длины в пикселях.

Более сложный - использовать средства *WinAPI* (`GetTextMetrics`, `GetTextExtentExPoint32`).